# Pauli Matrix Question

Tags: matrices

I'm working through a paper and can't complete a calculation, which seems very trivial.

The paper has a matrix $\mathbf{T}(z)$ which is a $2\times2$ matrix with elements bounded by $1$. Each entry contains a smooth function in $z$. The paper writes

$$-\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{3}\mathbf{T}\boldsymbol{}\sigma_{3} -\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{1}\mathbf{T}\boldsymbol{}\sigma_{1} = -2\mathbf{T}, $$

where 
$$\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}0\quad1 \\ 1 \quad 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \boldsymbol{\sigma}_{3} = \begin{bmatrix}1\quad 0\\ 0\quad -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Just solve this by brute force, you'll find that T is proportional to the identity matrix.

Comment: It doesn't give the result I quoted. it must be wrong!

Comment: If T is proportional to the identity you have $\sigma_3^2+\sigma_1^2=2I$ where I is the identity matrix right?

Comment: Yes...trying to figure out if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Define your matrix elements $T =\begin{pmatrix}t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} & t_{22}\end{pmatrix}$
Develop the equation and you'll find the set of 4 equations :

$\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}+t_{22}&-t_{12}+t_{21}\\t_{12}-t_{21}&t_{11}+t_{22} \end{pmatrix} = 2\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}&t_{12}\\ t_{21}&t_{22}\end{pmatrix}$
which is solved by $t_{12}=0$, $t_{21}=0$ and $t_{11}=t_{22}$.
Therefore, $T$ is proportional to the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had this written out, so I guess the authors just picked the elements to simplify...very applied maths I must say.